# Courtesy page when CSP frame-ancestors refuse the connection

Tags: content-security-policy

I would like to make my website embeddable only to selected domains so I've used the CSP directive frame-ancestors:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://example.com/;
```

It works well, in fact, when I try to embed a page from mysite it displays:

> mysite.com has refused the connection.

How can I show a courtesy page or a custom message instead of the one above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `'report-uri'` directive in your CSP header. It allows you to specify a URL where the browser will send reports when a violation of your CSP policy occurs. When a connection is refused by `'frame-ancestors'`, a cuystom message may be displayed.

1. Create custom page/message that you wish to display when connection are refused.
2. Host the aforementioned page and write down your fresh URL.
3. In CSP header of your main site, add the `report-uri` directive and set the URL as the value:

   Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://myexample.net/; report-uri https://myerrorsite.net/custom-message.html